# Formulário com um campo do tipo "file" chega ao servidor com "$_POST" vazio

Tags: php, upload, formulário-submeter, arquivo

No nosso servidor de alojamento, tenho dois projectos, onde ambos estão com um módulo na nossa área administrativa para gerir imagens.

No projecto **A**, o formulário é submetido para o servidor e a matriz de `$_POST` é recebida pelo servidor com o campo da imagem carregada.

No proejcto **B**, o formulário é submetido para o servidor mas a matriz de `$_POST` chega vazia ao servidor, apesar de no Firebug eu conseguir ver que o campo e a imagem carregada foram enviados.

#### Formulário

Igual para projecto **A** e **B**

```html
<form class="horizontal-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="#">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Carregar imagem</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                        <div class="input-append">
                            <div class="uneditable-input">
                                <i class="icon-file fileupload-exists"></i>
                                <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="btn btn-file">
                                <span class="fileupload-new">Selecionar ficheiro</span>
                                <span class="fileupload-exists">alterar</span>
                                <input type="file" class="default" name="img">
                            </span>
                            <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">remover</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="help-block">Escolha uma imagem para substituir a existente no site.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Pré-visualizar</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="thumbnail item" style="width:244px">
                        <a href="http://www.meusite.com/caminho/para/imagem/imagem.jpg" title="Pré-visualização da imagem: imagem.jpg" class="fancybox-button">
                            <div class="zoom">
                                <img src="http://www.meusite.com/caminho/para/imagem/imagem.jpg" alt="" />
                                <div class="zoom-icon"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="details">
                            imagem.jpg
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="help-block">Pré-visualizar imagem existente</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn blue"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Guardar alterações</button>
        <a class="btn" href="?mod=website&call=images" title="">cancelar</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### Informação do Firebug

- Projecto **A**

  [image: Captura Tela - Cabeçalhos]

  [image: Captura Tela - Post]

  [image: Captura Tela - Post Source]
- Projecto **B**

  [image: Captura Tela - Cabeçalhos]

  [image: Captura Tela - Post]

  [image: Captura Tela - Post Source]

---

Já realizei uma série de testes de forma a entender o que se possa estar a passar, alguns dos quais poderão ser relevantes para encontrar a solução para este problema:

1. Ficheiro de PHP com nada mais que o formulário em cima apresentado.

   No projecto **A** e **B** o `var_dump($_POST);` dá-me uma matriz vazia.
2. Adicionar campo extra do tipo `hidden` ou do tipo `text` ao formulário do projecto **B** resolve o problema e a matriz de `$_POST` passa a chegar ao servidor em condições.
3. Copiar ficheiro PHP do projecto **A** para o projecto **B** para verificar eventuais problemas com o ficheiro em si (*???*), mas o resultado é o mesmo.
4. Verificação dos ficheiros `.htaccess` para localizar alguma directiva ao Apache, mas ambos os ficheiros são rigorosamente iguais e não contém instruções além de:

   ```htaccess
   # Use PHP5 AS DEFAULT
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php

   # Frontpage
   # Set the files to be ignored when ussing the directory list

   IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
   IndexIgnore *


   # BROWERS SERVER FILES VIEW DISABLE
   Options -Indexes


   # CUSTOM ERROR DOCUMENTS FOR APPACHE REDIRECT
   ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.htm
   ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.htm
   ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.htm
   ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.htm
   ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.htm
   ```
5. Testar em diferentes navegadores e diferentes computadores para excluir problemas causados pelo navegador ou sessões.

   O resultado foi coerente em todos os testes, projecto **A** funciona bem, projecto **B** não funciona.

---

## Pergunta

Porque é que o mesmo formulário funciona no projecto **A**, mas falha no projecto **B** e os testes com um formulário simples em ambos os domínios falham quando esperaria que no projecto **A** funcionasse?

Comment: Dúvida: a afirmação "No projecto A e B o var_dump($_POST); dá-me uma matriz vazia." para contradizer o que você disse no segundo parágrafo. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Dúvida #2: reparei que nas imagens com o *source*, uma tem o atributo `name` com valor `filename` e outra com valor `img`. Está certo isso?

Comment: Já experimentou comparar os `phpinfo()` dos dois servidores? Pode ser alguma configuração diferente.

Comment: @utluiz Sim, dentro da área administrativa onde os formulários são utilizados, no projecto **A** funciona, no projecto **B** não. Mas se pegar num ficheiro só com um formulário lá dentro e meter na raiz de cada domínio e experimentar, não funciona em nenhum deles. Isto é muito esquisito mesmo...

Comment: @utluiz Sim, projecto **A** tem o nome de `filename` e o projecto **B** tem o nome de `img`, embora tenha andado a "brincar" com os nomes para ver se vinha daí (curto demais, longo demais...). Isto para testar alguma relação causa-efeito por conta do nome do `input`.

Comment: @bfavaretto Como referi, ambos os projectos estão no mesmo servidor de alojamento. O output do `phpinfo()` é rigorosamente igual para toda a malta presente nesta máquina, entre os quais os projectos **A** e **B** :)

Comment: Segundo [este tópico](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282909/php-post-array-empty-upon-form-submission) uma causa possível seria haver uma reescrita geral de URL para adicionar o "www" no endereço das requisições que não o tivessem. Tem algo assim configurado no Apache? Eu me lembro que quando configurava VirtualHosts no Apache eu mapeava os dois tipos de domínio (com e sem "www") para não ter problemas. Será que pode ser isso?

Comment: E talvez [este outro link](http://geekbrit.tumblr.com/post/1470396976/php-post-array-is-empty) lhe dê alguma ideia nova. Verifique ainda se no seu host tem arquivos de configuração "php.ini" específicos por diretório. Já usei isso em algumas hospedagens e pode causar confusão.

Comment: Zuul, quando você coloca um campo hidden a imagem chega no servidor também? Ou vai o valor do hidden mas não o do input file?

Comment: Algumas outra idéias: Verificar se o input file não está desabilitado, verificar se você está postando para a ação correta, verificar a variável `$_FILES`, e, finalmente, as configurações desse post em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3587158/664577

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Com qualquer outro input, todo o formulário chega ao servidor e a imagem é carregada como esperado! Em suma, com outro campo para além do `file`, funciona tudo bem.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Pronto, já está resolvido. Isto é mesmo algo que pronto... :D Basicamente estava a verificar o `$_POST` quando o formulário não tem nada a não ser `$_FILES` :) Adiciona por favor uma resposta alertando para este facto como foi o caso do teu comentário para que possa dar o assunto como resolvido. E um grande obrigado, estava tão envolvido em soluções complexas que nem vi a falha na verificação. _(**Nota:** No projecto **A** estava a verificar o `$_FILES`, no projecto **B** estava a verificar o `$_POST`)_ E obrigado aos demais pelo tempo dispensado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme [o manual do PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) a maneira adequada de tratar arquivos de *upload* em métodos POST é utilizando a variável global [$_FILES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php).

```php
// Uma vez que o nome do seu input file é img
$_FILES['img']['tmp_name']
```

No caso no OP, quando o formulário continha apenas um input file, somente a variável `$_FILES` era alimentada. Apenas ao incluir um *input hidden* ou algo do gênero o PHP carregava a representação dos dados desse input na variável `$_POST`.

---

Alguns outros pontos que podem gerar problemas (não relevantes para a situação do OP, mas que podem vir a ajudar outros usuários):

1. O formulário deve conter o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
2. O formulário deve conter o atributo `method="POST"` (ou `PUT`, mas esse é um mamute diferente)
3. Verifique se você esta usando **aspas duplas** (`"`) nos atributos HTML, as vezes você pode sem querer recortar e colar aspas inteligentes, aspas angulares, etc
4. Verifique se uma função JavasScript não está **desabilitando** o input ou a form
5. Verifique se seu input possui um **nome** (atributo `name`). Só o ID não é suficiente
6. Verifique se esse nome não possuí *underscores* (`_`)
7. Verifique se dois inputs não possuem o mesmo nome
8. Verifique se os diretórios envolvidos possuem **permissões de leitura e escrita**
9. Verifique se os diretórios temporários e de destino possuem **espaço livre em disco**
10. Verifique se o formulário está sendo corretamente fechado `</form>`
11. Verifique as configurações do **php.ini**; em especial `file_uploads`, `post_max_size` e `upload_max_file_size`
12. Verifique o arquivo `.htaccess`
13. Verifique se seu **arquivo de origem** não tem um problema para início de conversa, tente fazer upload de arquivos pequenos.

**Adaptado** [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3587158/664577) do usuário [shamittomar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180136/shamittomar) na Stack Overflow em inglês.